# About program crashes since startup, causing studio not to print error log problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Using a real machine test on the Android 8.0 system, the program crashed and restarted too quickly, resulting in no error log on Android studio causing the crash. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, create your app specific log beacause it clears the log if app crashes:

In Android Studio, the default setting for the Logcat window seems to be "Show only selected Application" (top right corner of the Logcat window). Which is looking at the log of the selected process (your current launch by default). So when your app crashes during testing, that process is gone, so the filter clears the log.

Instead, select "Edit Filter Configuration" and set up a filter for your app, like this:

FilterName: MyApp(Your Filter Name)

PackageName: com.example.myapp (<< replace with your app's package name)
...and then select that filter for future runs. This should keep the log there for you, even after the app crashes.

**OR** You can enable ADB Integration

1- Tools --> Android --> Enable ADB Integration.

and to see the logcat and the crashes as normal.

First option is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

**Me too, I had the same issues**

- **enable ADB Integration**

  Tools --> Android --> Enable ADB Integration

In Logcat window change "Show only selected Application" to "No Filter" 
and "Verbose" to "Error" you can see occurred errors